# Is there any easter egg in Sitecore?

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, experience-analytics

I am just curious whether there is an easter egg - inside joke, hidden message (image) or secret feature - that you have found in Sitecore in various versions.

Are there any?

Easter egg -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)

Comment: Point 38 of these release notes. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/top-50-gems-of-sitecore-7

Comment: Also; Unicorn has a few ;-)

Comment: Sounds like the hunt is on for the elusive answer to 38

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have previously found 2 secret CLI commands in Sitecore JSS:

elephant-in-the-room:

```
> jss elephant-in-the-room
JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder.
  _.-- ,.--.
  .'   .'    /
  | @       |'..--------._
  /      \._/              '.
/  .-.-                     \
(  /    \                     \
\\      '.                  | #
  \\       \   -.           /
  :\       |    )._____.'   \
    "       |   /  \  |  \    )
            |   |./'  :__ \.-'
            '--'

Won't someone please address me?
```

whats-the-password:

```
> jss whats-the-password
JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder.
Why it's b, of course.
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything else from JSS team than some Easter eggs ;)

Answer (score 19):

Maybe not an easter egg, but `MainUtil` class contains some "useful" methods like:

1. My favorites:

```
/// <summary>Returns false.</summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool False()
{
  return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns <c>true</c>.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool True()
{
  return true;
}
```

2. Method used by every single Sitecore developer:

```
/// <summary>Determines whether the specified string is empty.</summary>
/// <param name="s">The s.</param>
/// <returns>
///     <c>true</c> if the specified string is empty; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </returns>
public static bool IsEmpty(string s)
{
  if (s != null)
    return s.Length == 0;
  return true;
}
```

3. Very functional:

```
/// <summary>No-op</summary>
public static void Nop(params object[] obj)
{
}

/// <summary>Touch</summary>
public static void Touch(params object[] obj)
{
}
```

4. The one I cannot live without:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to call when doing silent catches. Causes the Resharper warning to disappear.
/// </summary>
public static void SilentCatch()
{
}
```

Comment: I think that these can be classified as Easter eggs as Easter eggs are also secret feature and these are definitely those kind of "features" :) Thanks for sharing

Comment: Interestingly, IsEmpty is basically the same as IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @Geoff Whoops! I'm not sure what was going through my mind, there. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

I was running some shell scripts to import data onto my website in Sitecore PowerShell ISE. And I found these.

[image]

[image]

[image]